# Нужно посчитать занятое время

Tags: python

есть сотрудник который работает с 9 до 18 и нужно занять это время

```
class Worker:
    def __init__(self, name, worktime):
        self.name = name
        self.worktime = worktime
    
    def time_busy(self, times):
        busy = какой то алгоритм
        return busy
```

передаем данные `Maxim = Worker('Maxim', [9, 18])`
далее к примеру мы озадачиваем Максима с 9 до 15 `Maxim = Worker.time_busy('Maxim', [9, 15])`

и я не понимаю какой алгоритм написать что бы на выходе я получил остаток рабочего времени, а именно то что осталось время с 15 до 18

Comment: что именно нужно получить на выходе? число 3? Список [15, 18]?

Comment: на выходе нужно получить список оставшегося времени (в данном случае с 15 до 18)

Comment: а если максим озадачем не с 9 до 15, а с 11 до 15, что нужно получить?

Comment: оу, получается нужно получить несколько списков с 9 до 11 и второй с 15 до 18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

задачу можно решать по разному - если она подразумевает, что можно указать несколько диапазонов (последовательно) когда работник занят и в результате вернуть все диапазоны, когда работник свободен

**способ 1:**

если дело касается только суток и целое кол-во часов, то можно обойтись малой кровью:

- создать список со свободными часами
- при вводе диапазона занятости удалять эти значения из списка (по сути собирая новый список)
- когда требуется вернуть свободные диапазоны - просто двигаться от начала списка к концу и если числа идут последовательно (например, 13, 14, 15) - включать их в единый диапазон (т.е. изменять начало и конец диапазона), а если числа с перерывом, то считать, что один диапазон закончился и надо начинать новый

**способ 2:**

если диапазон может включать и минуты (и секунды)

когда задача немного усложняется, но принцип тот же самый -

- надо идти по свободным диапазонам и если диапазон попадает (полностью или частично) в занятый диапазон - обрезать справа или слева время (или даже удалять диапазон) или из 1 диапазона формировать 2 диапазона, если "обрезание" происходит по центру

например свободный диапазон 10-20, а занятый 11-15, смотрим что левый коней занятого > левого конца свободного, но больше правого конца свободного - формируем новый свободный диапазон 10-11

и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, по итогу я получил 2 списка
[9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

как из них вычесть одинаковые значения?

Comment: например `res = [i for i in a if i not in b]`, а затем надо пройти и сформировать уже диапазоны